# Erreur de segmentation (core dumped)

Tags: npm, vue.js, terminal, ubuntu-16.04

please
how can i resolve this error on ubuntu? 
`Erreur de segmentation (core dumped)`
after run

> $ sudo npm i -g npm

also after run

> $ sudo npm install -g @vue/cli-init

I tried the instructions described in this link https://askubuntu.com/questions/690565/how-to-resolve-segmentation-fault-core-dumped without results

Comment: Which version of npm are you using ?
It's probably not a problem with vue, but with npm.

Comment: my npm version is 5.6.0   ( and my node version is 8.11.2)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and solved it.(my OS is ubuntu 19.4)

the reason that this problem happens, is you installed nodejs and npm separately.

so At first, you should remove nodejs and npm.

```
sudo apt --auto-remove purge npm
sudo apt --auto-remove purge nodejs
```

and then install just nodejs

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

At last, do following commands for checking nodejs and npm

```
node -v
npm -v
```